# Google Analytics GA4 real time visitors show a regular pattern but no visits according to server logs

Tags: google-analytics

A Google Analytics GA4 shows the following strange real-time visitor pattern:
[image]

The same pattern has been going on for a few hours. According to the server logs, there are no visitors on the site. It looks like someone (a bot) is playing with the Analytica ID of the site.

What can be done in this case?